# Reuse components in angular2 model driven forms

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, modulo

I'm fairly new to angular2 and for the past few days I have been trying to create reusable form components using model driven forms

So lets say we have a component `componentA.component.ts`

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'common-a',
    template: `
    <div [formGroup]="_metadataIdentifier">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Common A[1]</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="valueA1">
            <small>Description 1</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Common A[2]</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="valueA2">
            <small>Description 2</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})


export class ComponentA implements OnInit{

    @Input('group')
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            valueA1 : ['', [Validators.required]],
            valueA2 : ['', [Validators.required]],
        });
    }
}
```

And a component B `componentB.component.ts`

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'common-b',
    template: `
    <div [formGroup]="_metadataIdentifier">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Common B</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" formControlName="valueB">
            <small>Description</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})


export class ComponentB implements OnInit{

    @Input('group')
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm= this._fb.group({
            valueB : ['', [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
}
```

My question is how can I compose a form using this two sub components without moving the control of the inputs to the main component.
For example a `main.component.ts`

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: `
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
        <div>
            <common-a [group]="formA"></common-a>
            <common-b [group]="formB"></common-b>
            <div>
                <button>Register!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    `
})


export class Main implements OnInit{

    @Input('group')
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    public formA : FormGroup;

    public formB : FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            //how can I compose these two sub forms here
            //leaving the form control names agnostic to this component
        });
    }
}
```

The concept behind this idea is to build many complex forms that share some of their building blocks.

That is, I don't want my `Main` component to know the names of the `formControlNames` [`valueA1`,`valueA2`,`valueB`] but automagically insert them and update/validate on the top level form group.

Any ideas or points to the right direction would be helpfull.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be accomplish by passing in our top level `FormGroup` to the child component and having the child component add itself into the higher level `FormGroup` using `formGroupName` that way the upper level `FormGroup` needs to know essentially nothing about the lower levels:

**main.component.ts**

```
template: `<...>
    <common-a [parentForm]="myForm"></common-a>
    <...>
```

We will also get rid of the formA, formB declarations as they are no longer used.

**component-a.component.ts** `[formGroup]` is our parent group, `formGroupName` is how we will identify and attach the component's controls as a group to work in the larger whole (they will nest inside the parent group).

```
@Component({<...>
template: `
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Common A[1]</label>
    <div formGroupName="componentAForm">
        <input type="text" formControlName="valueA1">
        <small>Description 1</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Common A[2]</label>
    <div formGroupName="componentAForm">
        <input type="text" formControlName="valueA2">
        <small>Description 2</small>
    </div>
</div>`
})

export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
     @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
     componentAForm: FormGroup;

     constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

     ngOnInit() {
         this.componentAForm = this._fb.group({
             valueA1: ['', Validators.required],
             valueA2: ['', Validators.required]
         });

         this.parentForm.addControl("componentAForm", this.componentAForm);
     }
}
```

Here's a plunker *(note that I made component B a little more dynamic here just to see if it could be done, but the implementation above for is equally applicable to B)*: http://plnkr.co/edit/fYP10D45pCqiCDPnZm0u?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful and eye opening :)

Comment: New to angular, and started with model-driven forms right away. Out of curiosity, is this method of sharing *FormGroup* fields the recommended approach or a workaround? I am building a complex system and I try to focus on developing small components and then reuse them in a parent-child relationship (4-5 levels).