# How can I add a formGroup to another formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I found this answer which shows how I can add form controls to the parent form:

[Reuse components in angular2 model driven forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891559/reuse-components-in-angular2-model-driven-forms)

but I would like to be able to add new formGroups to different areas of the page like this.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <!--... other inputs -->
  <md-tab-group formGroupName="nutrition">
    <md-tab formGroupName="calories">
      <template md-stretch-tabs="always" md-tab-label>Calories</template>
      <template md-tab-content>
        <calories></calories> <!-- I want to add controll groups like this-->
      </template>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab formGroupName="carbs">
      <template md-stretch-tabs="always" md-tab-label>Carbs</template>
      <template md-tab-content>
        <carbs></carbs>
      </template>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</form>
```

the whole form model should look like this:

```
{
   name: '',
   nutrition:{
      calories: {
        total: ''
        // more
      },
      carbs: {
        total: ''
        // more
      }
}
```

I have been able to add the `nutrition` formGroup like this:

`<nutrition [parentForm]="myForm"></nutrition>`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'nutrition',
  template: `
  <div [formGroup]="parentForm"></div>
  `
})
export class NutritionComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;

    nutritionGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.nutritionGroup = new FormGroup({
        blank: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      });
      this.parentForm.addControl('nutrition', this.nutritionGroup);
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to pass in the `nutrition` form group to the `calories` formGroup like this:

`<calories [parentControl]="nutrition"></calories>`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'calories',
  template: ``
})
export class CaloriesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() parentControl: FormGroup;
  caloriesForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.caloriesForm = new FormGroup({
        blank: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      });

    this.parentControl.addControl('calories', this.caloriesForm);
  }
}
```

**Can this be done?**

Comment: have you got the solution  for this ?  i have same problem

Comment: yes and no. I'm implementing an ngrx store solution now. I can have as many forms comprising a single parent form which individually save their values to my store. The submit button then dispatches an action that calls the values from the store. Beware of validator complexities with this solution.

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 8):

If you are (or anyone is) still interested, after adding the control to your `parentControl`, you need to emit it back to the parent component, so it can be updated.

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() onFormGroupChange: EventEmitter<FormGroup> = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();

this.parentControl.addControl('calories', this.caloriesForm);
this.onFormGroupChange.emit(this.parentControl);
```

On parent html element, you need to reasign it back to `parentControl`:
`(onFormGroupChange)="setParentControl($event)"`

And the method on your ts

```
public setParentControl(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    this.myForm = formGroup;
}
```

Then you will have the control in your FormGroup `myForm` and do whatever you like, on your parent element:
`console.log(this.myForm.controls['calories'])`

Haven't included all the code, but only what you need :)